# VaR of future foreign currency income stream

Tags: volatility, fx, value-at-risk

Assume I have a series of future incomes in a single foreign currency.

How do I calculate the total VaR for this forex risk using the volatility method?

My first thought was that I could simply add up the VaR for each future income, i.e. for receiving $V_1, V_2, ..., V_n$ at times $T_1, T_2, ..., T_n$ the 95% VaR would be:

$$\operatorname{VaR}_{0.95} = -1.65\sum_i{\sigma V_i \sqrt{T_i}}$$

but is this correct?

Comment: VaR is not an additive function of the assets or incomes. Especially since those incomes are not mutually independent.

Comment: It seems to me a step is missing: the future cash flows should be combined together in some sort of Present Value...